# Add a Datepicker in a Fancybox in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, jquery

I added a Datepicker in an ajax fancybox.
My Code is

```
<script>
require(['jquery','rbpopup','mage/calendar'], function($){

$('.fancyboxlive').fancybox({
            type: 'ajax',
            title: 'Admin',
            maxWidth    : 800,
            maxHeight   : 400,
            fitToView   : false,
            width       : '70%',
            height      : '70%',
            autoSize    : false,
            closeClick  : false,
            openEffect  : 'elastic',
            closeEffect : 'none',
});
$(document).on('click','.closeFancybox',function(){
            $.fancybox.close();
});
});
</script>

 <a class="fancyboxlive" href="<?php echo $url; ?>?id=<?php echo $collectionData->getId(); ?>" > <?php echo __('Edit') ?></a>
```

How can I add the Datepicker inside the fancybox popup?

Comment: I believe this is just pure Javascript. You should ask it on SO not no Magento SE.

Comment: ok i already resolve this issue using iframe.